# local file access in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm encountering an issue with some local web prototyping;

I've been working on a single page which access files on my C:/ by starting my Chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files.
This is great, I've got my first page working successfully and it loads in my .js,.css files etc as expected.

However, when I click the link to proceed to the next page, the HTML loads, but none of the styles, javascript (or even images) load.

I'm receiving 'Failed to load resource' errors in the console, despite the file:// url pointing to the correct location.

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lieu of a solution, some advice: Set up a web server on your computer for testing. Developing in an environment that's similar to a "production" environment, as opposed to working around the quirks of local file access, will save you quite a bit of time in the long run.

There are a number of tools that will help you set up a development web server; [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is a popular one.